# How to calculate Rating in my MongoDB design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, architecture, mongoose

I'm creating a system that users can write review about an item and rate it from 0-5. I'm using MongoDB for this. And my problem is to find the best solution to calculate the total rating in product schema. I don't think querying all comments to get the size and dividing it by total rating is a good solution. Here is my Schema. I appreciate any advice:

Comments:

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
Rating : {  type: Number, default:0 },
Helpful : {  type: Number, default:0 },
User :{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
     },
Content: String,


});
```

Here is my Item schema:

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
 //id is barcode
_id : String,
Rating : {  type: Number, default:0 },
Comments :[
    {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'comments'
    }
],

});
```

---

EDIT: HERE is the solution I got from another topic : [calculating average in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810599/calculating-average-in-mongoose/26811305#26811305)

Comment: Do you really want the *total* (as in sum) of ratings, or don't you rather want the *average*?

Comment: @Philipp I want the average cause the final rating has to be between 0-5 aswell.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the total using the aggregation framework. First you use the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator to turn the comments into a document stream:

```
 { $unwind: "$Comments" }
```

The result is that for each product-document is turned into one product-document per entry in its `Comments` array. That comment-entry is turned into a single object under the field `Comments`, all other fields are taken from the originating product-document.

Then you use [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to rejoin the documents for each product by their _id, while you use the [$avg](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operator to calculate the average of the rating-field:

```
 { $group: {
     _id: "$_id",
     average: { $avg: "$Comments.Rating" }
 } }
```

Putting those two steps into an aggregation pipeline calculates the average rating for every product in your collection. You might want to narrow it down to one or a small subset of products, depending on what the user requested right now. To do this, prepend the pipeline with a [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) step. The $match object works just like the one you pass to `find()`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So does this mean I can delete Rating: from my product Schema? SHould I add product id to my Rating Schema? And I also where/How should I write your code in mongoose? Should i use it like this: Product.aggregate([
        { $match: {
            _id: req.body.id
        }},
        { $unwind: "$Comments" },
        { $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            average: { $avg: "$Comments.Rating"  }
        }}
    ]

Comment: This aggregation does not require the rating-field in the product. However, when a user giving rating happens a lot less frequently than a user querying the product, you could optimize query performance by recalculating the rating as I demonstrated whenever a user posts a rating and cache the result in the product document. This allows you to get the rating without having to recalculate it with an aggregation on every pageview.

Comment: Philip your code doesn't calculate the average. The average is always 0. I wrote exactly what I wrote in my previous comment. this is what i get as result : [ { _id: '0747532699', average: 0 } ]. 0747532699 is my product id

Comment: Apparently i cannot reference Comments.Rating since it's in another collection. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Referencing instead of embedding is always problematic in MongoDB. It is not a relational database, after all. But when you add another field to the comment document which references the product it applies to, you could query the comment collection and group it by the product.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying question that it would be useful to understand is *why* you don't think that finding all of the ratings, summing them up, and dividing by the total number is a useful approach. Understanding the underlying reason would help drive a better solution.

Based on the comments below, it sounds like your main concern is performance and the need to run map-reduce (or another aggregation framework) each time a user wants to see total ratings.

This person addressed a similar issue here: http://markembling.info/2010/11/using-map-reduce-in-a-mongodb-app

The solution they identified was to separate out the execution of the map-reduce function from the need in the view to see the total value. In this case, the optimal solution would be to run the map-reduce periodically and store the results in another collection, and have the average rating based on the collection that stores the averages, rather than doing the calculation in real-time each time.

As I mentioned in the previous version of this answer, you can improve performance further by limiting the map-reduce to addresing ratings that were created or updated more recently, or since the last map-reduce aggregation.

Comment: Your posting gives valuable input, but unfortunately it doesn't answer the question. So I am afraid I have to downvote it unless you edit it to add an actual solution to the problem.

Comment: Well yes I want to avoid map-reduce and I think it is not optimal to query all ratings and divide by size every time a user wants to see the rating. I was think maybe I can delete Product and just add product ID in my Comments this way I have to deal with only 1 schema but still i have to query Comments.find(_id:item-id){ }. I'm really confused about this.

Comment: @Philipp - it depends on what Hirad's question was. I think he was less concerned with how to perform the actual operation, and more concerned with reducing the scope of the operation. So I thought that adding in a map-reduce example here is overkill. I appreciate why you downvoted my answer, though, and have updated it to reflect your feedback.