# How to get a rating average in Mongoose / node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a star rating directive working on the front end for angularjs, I can save a rating to the rating  collection. 
here is my rating schema / model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Rating', {
    bourbonId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Bourbon'},
    userId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    rating:     {type: Number, required: true},
    ratingId : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId}

});
```

Here is the item that I need an average rating for:

```
 'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    BourbonSchema = null;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bourbon', {
    BourbonId:    {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId},
    name:  {type: String, required: true},
    blog:  {type: String, required: true},
    photo: {type: String, required: true},
    ratings: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Rating'},
    rating: {type: Number}

});

var Bourbon = mongoose.model('Bourbon', BourbonSchema);
module.exports = Bourbon;
```

I need to find a way to match by bourbon ID. From looking at stack overflow, it seems using an aggregate function may be the way to go. [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810599/calculating-average-in-mongoose/26811305#26811305)

Here is the current broken code I have in my controller. I know it's way off, along with failed attempts that i've had using async.map to try and solve this as well:

```
    'use strict';

var Bourbon = require('../../../models/bourbon'),
    Rating = require('../../../models/rating');
    //async = require('async');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Get Bourbons',
    notes: 'Get Bourbons',
    tags:['bourbons'],
    handler: function(request, reply){
        Bourbon.find(function(err, bourbons){
            Bourbon.findOne(id, 'Rating', function(err, bourbon){
                Rating.aggregate([
                    {$match: {bourbonId: {$in: bourbon.ratings}}},
                    {$group: {bourbonId: bourbon._id, average: {$avg: '$rating'}}}
                ], function(err, result){
                    bourbon.rating = result;
                    reply({bourbons:bourbons});
                    console.log('Bourbs', bourbons);
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

any help would be much appreciated. Beating my head against a brick wall, just throwing random code out now. ..

---

here's what i've implemented: 
model:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    BourbonResultSchema = null;


module.exports = mongoose.model('BourbonResult', {
    _Id:    {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, 'ref': 'Bourbon'},
    avgRating: {type: Number}

});


var BourbonResult = mongoose.model('BourbonResult', BourbonResultSchema, null);
module.exports = BourbonResult;
```

---

controller:

```
  'use strict';

var Bourbon = require('../../../models/bourbon'),
    Rating = require('../../../models/rating'),
    BourbonResult = require('../../../models/bourbonResult');
    //async = require('async');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Get Bourbons',
    notes: 'Get Bourbons',
    tags:['bourbons'],
    handler: function(request, reply){

            Rating.aggregate(
                [
                    {'$group':{
                        '_id': '$bourbonId',
                        'avgRating': {'$avg': '$rating'}
                    }}
                ],
                function(err,bourbons){
                    // Map plain results to mongoose document objects
                    bourbons = bourbons.map(function(result){
                        return new BourbonResult(result);
                    });

                    Bourbon.populate(bourbons,{'path': '_id'},function(err,bourbons){
                        reply({bourbons:bourbons});
                        console.log('BourbsRESSSSSS', JSON.stringify(bourbons, undefined, 2));
                    });
                }
            );

    }
};
```

here's what I get back from the consolelog:

```
BourbsRESSSSSS [ { _id: 
     { _id: 54acf382894ee2bcdebbc7f5,
       name: 'example2',
       photo: 'http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg',
       blog: 'example2',
       __v: 0 },
    avgRating: 3.3333333333333335 },
  { _id: 
     { _id: 54a77e0fe63c850000f1269c,
       name: 'example',
       photo: 'http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg',
       blog: 'example',
       __v: 0 },
    avgRating: 3 } ]
```

========================================================================

Perfect!

Comment: This solution seems cool! But what i end up doing is everytime someone rates y calculate the new average and store it on the original model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is list the "average" rating against each "Bourbon" here in your output there are probably a couple of approaches. But one of the cleaner ways would be to utilize mongoose populate on a special object model representing the structure of the results from aggregation.

You don't appearhave any other "types" of "Ratings" here other than for "bourbon", so it stands to reason that you just want to aggregate the whole collection.

```
// Set up a schema and model to match result structure
var bourbonResultSchema = new Schema({
    "_id": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Bourbon" },
    "avgRating": Number
});

// The "null" for the collection is because there will not be any physical storage
var BourbonResult = mongoose.model( "BourbonResult", bourbonResultSchema, null );


// Aggregate an mapping code

Rating.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$bourbonId",
            "avgRating": { "$avg": { "$ifNull": ["$rating",0 ] } }    
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Map plain results to mongoose document objects
        results = results.map(function(result) {
            return new BourbonResult(result);
        });

        Bourbon.populate(results,{ "path": "_id" },function(err,results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            reply(results);
            console.log( JSON.stringify( results, undefined, 2 ) );
        })
    }
);
```

So you define a schema and model that will match the structure of the results returned from aggregate. This is done so you can call `.populate()` later.

The results returned from aggregate are not mongoose documents, but just plain objects. You then cast all the results to `BourbonResult` objects by passing them through the `.map()` method in order to return an array of `BourbonResult`.

Since these are not mongoose documents, you can call the model method of `.populate()`, which takes an array of mongoose documents as the first argument. The second "options" argument tells the method which field path to use for the popluation, which is `_id` as defined earlier to reference the `Bourbon` model.

In the callback to `.populate()` the returned results merge both the average score returned from aggregation and the complete `Bourbon` object within the `_id` field. If you really wished, you could also run further `.populate()` statements over each `Bourbon` object in order to pull in any of it's references. A bit more complicated but possible.

As a note, the "bourbonId" field in the "Bourbon" model is probably a bit redundant. MongoDB always has a unique `_id` field present and the actual value used by referenced object links is that field unless specified otherwise. Even if you needed to define a reference there as I have done for `BourbonResult` then you can do that as well.

---

A complete listing with amended schema examples:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String
});

var ratingSchema = new Schema({
  "bourbonId": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Bourbon" },
  "userId": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "User" },
  "rating": { "type": Number, "required": true }
});

var bourbonSchema = new Schema({
  "name": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "blog": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "photo": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "ratings": [{ "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Rating" }],
  "rating": { "type": Number }
});

var bourbonResultSchema = new Schema({
  "_id": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  "avgRating": Number
});

var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema ),
    Rating = mongoose.model( "Rating", ratingSchema ),
    Bourbon = mongoose.model( "Bourbon", bourbonSchema ),
    BourbonResult = mongoose.model(
      "BourbonResult", bourbonResultSchema, null );


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bourbon");

async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([User,Rating,Bourbon],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },
      function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    },

    function(callback) {
      Bourbon.create({
        "name": 'test',
        "blog": 'test',
        "photo": 'test'
      },callback);
    },

    function(bourbon,callback) {
      User.create({ "name": 'ted' },function(err,user) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        Rating.create({
          "bourbonId": bourbon,
          "userId": user,
          "rating": 5
        },function(err,rating1) {
          callback(err,user,bourbon,rating1)
        });
      });
    },

    function(user,bourbon,rating1,callback) {
      Rating.create({
        "bourbonId": bourbon,
        "userId": user,
        "rating": 7
      },function(err,rating2) {
        callback(err,bourbon,rating1,rating2);
      });
    },

    function(bourbon,rating1,rating2,callback) {
      Bourbon.findById(bourbon.id,function(err,bourbon) {
        bourbon.ratings.push(rating1,rating2);
        bourbon.save(function(err,bourbon) {
          callback(err)
        });
      });
    },

    function(callback) {
      Rating.aggregate(
        [
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$bourbonId",
            "avgRating": { "$avg": { "$ifNull": ["$rating", 0 ] } }
          }},
        ],
        function(err,results) {
          console.log(results);

          results = results.map(function(result) {
            return new BourbonResult(result);
          });

          Bourbon.populate(
            results,
            { "path": "_id" },
            function(err,results) {
              console.log(results);
              callback(err);
            }
          )

        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
)
```

Gives output:

```
[ { _id: 54af7581efc755470845005c, avgRating: 6 } ]
[ { _id:
     { _id: 54af7581efc755470845005c,
       name: 'test',
       blog: 'test',
       photo: 'test',
       __v: 1,
       ratings: [ 54af7581efc755470845005e, 54af7581efc755470845005f ] },
    avgRating: 6 } ]
```

Comment: thanks! It seems to be giving me the correct average for each bourbon, but for some reason, I'm getting "null" for the _id. I'm thinking i'll need that to be able to find the rating by bourbonId, so I can display them rating on each bourbon correctly within the NG-repeat in angular. I'll add what i've implemented above.                  
Sorry, if the questions is a bit 'noobish' really new to mongoose and programming in general.

Comment: @user3709602 `null` for the `_id` where? The field in ratings is "bourbonId" as shown in your schema is it not? It is present in the documents I hope and that you did not forget to save the documents with this value.

Comment: Yes. It is saved correctly in the document: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54af648b604ba600003647bd"),
    "bourbonId" : ObjectId("54a77e0fe63c850000f1269c"),
    "rating" : 4,
    "userId" : ObjectId("54a2fcaefea8e3133476de35"),
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: matches this bourbonId: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a77e0fe63c850000f1269c"),
    "name" : "example",
    "photo" : "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg",
    "blog" : "example"
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: @user3709602 Thanks. Clearly the aggregate is working but just trying to trace down what is going wrong after that. BTW the intent here is that you do not call this within `Bourbon.find()` as you have. It actually replaces all of that code.

Comment: @user3709602 Brain snap. I wrote in the wrong model to call `.populate()` from. It should be `Bourbon` and not `BourbonResult`. Ammended.

Comment: Thanks again, I just realized, since it returns the complete bourbon object, the find shouldn't be necessary. Still trying to debug what's up with the _id: null.

Comment: @user3709602 Look at the answer as I edited it to correct the problem which was exactly what I said.

Comment: Thanks, You're awesome, and it all makes sense!! Hopefully, i'll be as knowledgeable as yourself someday.

Comment: One thing I've noticed. When the admin creates a new bourbon (item), it the get does not display the bourbon in the ng-repeat unless it has a rating.. Trying to work around it now, but any tips to save time would be MUCH  appreciated. thx.

Comment: @user3709602 Make it a required field in your schema or at least define a default of 0. You want it there always. You can also use [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to correct bad data where this is not present as is shown.

Comment: @user3709602 But really the thing here is that you are getting the results from "Ratings" and not from "Bourbon". So unless there is a rating, tools like the aggregation framework cannot create a 0 value out of thin air. Generally how databases work. You can always re-query your "Bourbon" collection and just match the found results from the aggregation against the collection items and default the rating to 0. But you cannot do that in one query. The question is answered as is and answers what was asked. If you have a new question then post a new question.

Comment: true. It will most likely need to be re-queried. Initially, the bourbon is made without any rating (users later rate the bourbon added by the admin), and as you said, results are from the ratings. Correct as usual.

Comment: @user3709602 Really long answer to that on another question here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/28057973/2313887

Comment: Thanks for the referenced link: stackoverflow.com/a/28057973/2313887 . I've been going over it the past few hours. This is getting in deeper from the basic find, create, updates, etc.. I've dealt with so far..  Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question, but should I be breaking this up into 2 different features in my router / controller ( A get for the find, a put for the update)? I know i'm off with something. I'm not able to get the console log on the server side for results. I've edited the question to show the new code above.

Comment: nvm. I got way too sloppy (remove, etc) . Going to sleep on it, I think I see where I was way off. You answered this questions perfect, and I see its use case. If I still have issues, I'll open  new question and be much more polished / specific.