# Merge collections to get average rating, but still get all of original collection before a rating has been given. Mongoose / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an admin that creates an item (a bourbon), that users can give a comment on and rating within that comment. I was able to aggregate the comments, but was not able to display newly-created bourbons, only those already seeded that already had ratings. i've tried to implement something similar to this thread: [referenced thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049610/mongodb-merge-related-collection-item-count-with-other-collection-results/28057973#28057973), but i'm am not doing something correct.

I'm a noob, and mainly play in the frontend, and am very confused about how I should change this sample code into actual production code. I see what each function is doing, but still fuzzy on it.

Should I do an async.each and set the aggregate function as the iterator..? I know this is busted. I've tried a few things now. Keep getting a 500 error, nothing on the console.log. Any help for this noob, much appreciated.

Here are my schemas: 
bourbon:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    BourbonSchema = null;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bourbon', {
    name:  {type: String, required: true},
    blog:  {type: String, required: true},
    photo: {type: String, required: true, default:'http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg'},
    location: {type: String, required: true},
    distillery: {type: String, required: true},
    avgRating: {type: Number}
});

var Bourbon = mongoose.model('Bourbon', BourbonSchema);
module.exports = Bourbon;
```

comments:

```
    'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', {
    bourbonId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Bourbon'},
    userId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    text:     {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date,  required: true, default: Date.now},
    rating  : {type: Number, required: true},
    votes:     {type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

this is my find / get in the controller, which I tried piecing together from the referenced link, but is slopp now:

```
    'use strict';

var Bourbon = require('../../../models/bourbon'),
    Comment = require('../../../models/comment'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    db = new DataStore(),
    async = require('async');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Get Bourbons',
    notes: 'Get Bourbons',
    tags: ['bourbons'],
    handler: function(request, reply){

        async.waterfall(
            [
                function(comment,callback){
                    async.series(
                        [

                            function(callback){
                                Bourbon.find({},function(err,results){
                                    async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback){
                                        db.insert({
                                            'bourbonId': result._id.toString(),
                                            'location' : result.location,
                                            'blog'     : result.blog,
                                            'distillery': result.distillery,
                                            'name': result.name,
                                            'avgRating': 0
                                        },callback);
                                    },callback);
                                });
                            },

                            function(callback){
                                Comment.aggregate(
                                    [
                                        {'$group':{
                                            '_id': '$bourbonId',
                                            'avgRating':{
                                                '$avg':'$rating'
                                            }
                                        }}
                                    ],
                                    function(err,results){
                                        async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback){
                                            db.update(
                                                {'bourbonId': result._id.toString()},
                                                {'$set':{
                                                    'avgRating': result.avgRating
                                                }
                                                },
                                                callback
                                            );
                                        },callback);
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        ],
                    function(err) {
                        if (err) callback(err);
                        db.find({},{'_id': 0},callback);
                    }
                    );
                }
            ],
            function(err,results){
                reply({results: results});
                console.log('LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOK',JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 4));
                process.exit();
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: Try to focus on one part of this at a time. You have broken all the server code so just work with than and in a separate and isolated area until you get it right. You have mistransposed a lot here. Those operations should be in "series" and not "waterfall" really as you're not passing anything around. They also need wrapping function definitions to pass the callback to move on to the next. In short you've misunderstood and cut out too much from what you are copying from.

Comment: Okay. I will do that.

Comment: This updated edit is what I had. I get a 200, but nothing console.logs for the result

Comment: should docs still be returning an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have more to learn about callbacks and sequencing. This is all the code inside your request handler that you need. Of course changing to send the response when you see what is happening.

```
async.series(
  [
    // List out exiting collection with 0 average
    function(callback) {
      Bourbon.find({},function(err,results){
        async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback){
          var plain = result.toObject()
          plain.bourbonId = plain._id.toString();
          plain.avgRating = 0;
          delete plain._id;

          db.insert(plain,callback); // next each iteration
        },callback);                  // move to next in series
      });
    },

    // Get aggregate results and update the items you just wrote
    function(callback) {
      Comment.aggregate(
        [
          { '$group': {
            '_id': '$bourbonId',
            'avgRating':{ '$avg':'$rating' }
          }}
        ],
        function(err,results) {
          async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback){
            db.update(
              {  'bourbonId': result._id.toString() },
              {'$set': {'avgRating': result.avgRating } },
              callback                   // next each iteration
            );
          },callback);                   // next in series "last"  
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  // This is called when both in the series are complete
  function(err) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    db.find({},{'_id': 0},function(err,docs) {
        console.log( docs );
    });
  }
);
```

The aim here is:

1. Put 0 values in a hash table ( here using nedb ) for all items
2. Get aggregation results from the other collection
3. Update the copy of all items with those items that actually have a value
4. When all is done then you read back your hash table

---

Full working example:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    db = new DataStore(),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String
});

var ratingSchema = new Schema({
  "bourbonId": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Bourbon" },
  "userId": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "User" },
  "rating": { "type": Number, "required": true }
});

var bourbonSchema = new Schema({
  "name": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "blog": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "photo": { "type": String, "required": true },
  "ratings": [{ "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Rating" }],
  "rating": { "type": Number }
});

var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema ),
    Rating = mongoose.model( "Rating", ratingSchema ),
    Bourbon = mongoose.model( "Bourbon", bourbonSchema );


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bourbon");

async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([User,Rating,Bourbon],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },
      function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    },

    function(callback) {
      Bourbon.create({
        "name": 'test',
        "blog": 'test',
        "photo": 'test'
      },callback);
    },

    function(bourbon,callback) {
      Bourbon.create({
        "name": 'another',
        "blog": 'another',
        "photo": 'another'
      },callback);
    },

    function(bourbon,callback) {
      User.create({ "name": 'ted' },function(err,user) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        Rating.create({
          "bourbonId": bourbon,
          "userId": user,
          "rating": 5
        },function(err,rating1) {
          callback(err,user,bourbon,rating1)
        });
      });
    },

    function(user,bourbon,rating1,callback) {
      Rating.create({
        "bourbonId": bourbon,
        "userId": user,
        "rating": 7
      },function(err,rating2) {
        callback(err,bourbon,rating1,rating2);
      });
    },

    function(bourbon,rating1,rating2,callback) {
      Bourbon.findById(bourbon.id,function(err,bourbon) {
        bourbon.ratings.push(rating1,rating2);
        bourbon.save(function(err,bourbon) {
          callback(err)
        });
      });
    },

    function(callback) {
      async.series(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Bourbon.find({},function(err,results) {
              if (err) callback(err);
              async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback) {
                var plain = result.toObject();
                plain.bourbonId = plain._id.toString();
                plain.avgRating = 0;
                delete plain._id;

                db.insert(plain,callback);
              },callback);
            });
          },

          function(callback) {
            Rating.aggregate(
              [
                { "$group": {
                  "_id": "$bourbonId",
                  "avgRating": { "$avg": "$rating" }
                }}
              ],
              function(err,results) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback) {
                  db.update(
                    { "bourbonId": result._id.toString() },
                    { "$set": { "avgRating": result.avgRating } },
                    callback
                  );
                },callback);
              }
            );
          }
        ],
        function(err) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          db.find({},{ '_id': 0 },callback);
        }
      );
    }

  ],
  function(err,results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log( results );
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Returns results as expected:

```
[ { name: 'test',
    blog: 'test',
    photo: 'test',
    __v: 0,
    ratings: [],
    bourbonId: '54c17bea8aa5f8c9161f5b6e',
    avgRating: 0 },
  { name: 'another',
    blog: 'another',
    photo: 'another',
    __v: 1,
    ratings: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    bourbonId: '54c17bea8aa5f8c9161f5b6f',
    avgRating: 6 } ]
```

Comment: @user3709602 You are still doing something wrong or your data is at fault. I've posted a complete working listing modified from the original code listing I gave you.

Comment: it was the data. I'm getting it going, but the issue I get now, is on page-refresh, it runs this and duplicates each bourbon.

Comment: @user3709602 Again that is another question. But the code I have given you is not at fault. It would seem you are doing something wrong in your client like "appending" when you should be "replacing". Post another question if you cannot work it out. We can't fix your application in one question only. And please fill in some details on your profile. Anonymous user accounts make everyone nervous to bother responding :)

Comment: Hey, just seeing if you had any insight on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116054/aggregate-function-duplicates-items-in-ng-repeat-on-page-refresh-need-to-figure/28119117?noredirect=1#comment44614547_28119117  . Tried everything on client side i could think of. Wondering if I should be implementing findAndModify somehow here on the server side.