# Aggregate function duplicates items in ng-repeat on page refresh. Need to figure out how to stop the duplication. Angularjs Mongodb mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angularjs-filter

I have items in a collection that run through this aggregate to find them with an average rating and to find them when they have not yet been commented on / rated yet.

It works, but everytime I refresh the page now, it makes a duplicate on display within the ng-repeat of each item in the bourbon collection. The actual amount of items in the bourbon collection is not changing. How do I stop this?
SERVER SIDE:
bourbon schema:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    BourbonSchema = null;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bourbon', {
    name:  {type: String, required: true},
    blog:  {type: String, required: true},
    photo: {type: String, required: true, default:'http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg'},
    location: {type: String, required: true},
    distillery: {type: String, required: true},
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Comments'}],
    rating : {type: Number}
});

var Bourbon = mongoose.model('Bourbon', BourbonSchema);
module.exports = Bourbon;
```

comment/rating schema:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', {
    bourbonId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Bourbon'},
    userId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    text:     {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date,  required: true, default: Date.now},
    rating  : {type: Number, required: true},
    votes:     {type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

aggregate function:

```
'use strict';

var Bourbon = require('../../../models/bourbon'),
    Comment = require('../../../models/comment'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    db = new DataStore(),
    async = require('async');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Get Bourbons',
    notes: 'Get Bourbons',
    tags: ['bourbons'],
    handler: function(request, reply){

        async.series(
            [
                function(callback){
                    Bourbon.find({},function(err,results){
                        //if (err) callback(err);
                        async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback){
                            var plain = result.toObject();
                            plain.bourbonId = plain._id.toString();
                            plain.avgRating = 0;
                            delete plain._id;

                            db.insert(plain,callback);
                        },callback);
                    });
                },

                function(callback){
                    Comment.aggregate(
                        [
                            {$group:{
                                _id: '$bourbonId',
                                avgRating:{$avg:'$rating'}
                            }}
                        ],
                        function(err,results){
                            async.eachLimit(results,10,function(result,callback){
                                db.update(
                                    {bourbonId: result._id.toString()},
                                    {$set: {avgRating: result.avgRating}},
                                    callback                   
                                );
                            },callback);                 
                        }
                    );
                }
            ],

            function(err){
                //if (err) callback(err);
                db.find({}, {_id: 0}, function(err, bourbons){
                    console.log('DOOOOCS', bourbons);
                    reply ({bourbons:bourbons});
                });
            });
    }
};
```

CLIENT side

```
factory:

(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('hapi-auth')
        .factory('Bourbon', ['$http', function($http){

            function create(bourbon){
                return $http.post('/admin', bourbon);
            }

            function all(){
                return $http.get('/admin');
            }

            return {create:create, all:all};
        }]);
})();
```

controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('hapi-auth')
        .controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', 'Bourbon', function($scope, Bourbon){
            //$scope.blog.photo = [];
            $scope.bourbon = {};
            $scope.bourbons = [];

            Bourbon.all().then(function(res){
                $scope.bourbons = res.data.bourbons;
                console.log(res.data.bourbons);
            });

            $scope.createBourbon = function(bourbon){
                console.log('BOURBB', bourbon);
                Bourbon.create(bourbon).then(function(res){
                    console.log('bourboonnnn', res.data);
                    $scope.bourbons.push(res.data);

                });
            };


        }]);
})();
```

jade:

```
.row
   .small-4.columns
   .small-4.columns
      .review
         .insertContainer(ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons')
            .adminName Name: {{bourbon.name}}
            img.bourbonImg(src='{{bourbon.photo}}')
            .adminBlog {{bourbon.blog.slice(0,200)}} ...
   .small-4.columns
```

trying to stop duplication of items in bourbon collection on page refresh.... 
Not sure if I need to implement some sort of replace method here.. a bit stuck now..

This is what the console log in the controller / aggregate function returns:

```
DOOOOCS [ { name: 'woodford reserve',
    location: 'kentucky',
    distillery: 'woodford',
    blog: 'fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj',
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    photo: 'http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg',
    bourbonId: '54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c',
    avgRating: 0 },
  { name: 'woodford reserve',
    location: 'kentucky',
    distillery: 'woodford',
    blog: 'fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj',
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    photo: 'http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg',
    bourbonId: '54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c',
    avgRating: 0 } ]
```

it seems to duplicate each item in the Bourbons collection whenever this function is run... , which it runs on page refresh as the Bourbon.all within the angular controller.

this is the bourbon in the collection, before it runs through the aggregate:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c"),
    "name" : "woodford reserve",
    "location" : "kentucky",
    "distillery" : "woodford",
    "blog" : "fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj",
    "comments" : [],
    "photo" : "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

---

updated jade w/ track by:

```
.row
   .small-4.columns
   .small-4.columns
      .review
      .insertContainer(ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons | unique: bourbon.bourbonId | filter: query')

            .adminName Name: {{bourbon.name}}
            img.bourbonImg(src='{{bourbon.photo}}')
            .adminBlog {{bourbon.blog.slice(0,200)}} ...
   .small-4.columns
```

this allows the items to show on the first load, but on any refresh / reload, I now get this error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: bourbon in bourbons track by bourbon.bourbonId | filter:query, Duplicate key: 54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c, Duplicate value: {"name":"woodford reserve","location":"kentucky","distillery":"woodford","blog":"fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj","__v":0,"comments":[],"photo":"http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg","bourbonId":"54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c","avgRating":0}
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=bourbon%20in%20bourbons…C%22bourbonId%22%3A%2254c2aa5556267e0000b5618c%22%2C%22avgRating%22%3A0%7D
    at http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:24483:21)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:14092:13)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:14225:29)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:14488:24)
    at done (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:9646:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:9836:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:7070/vendor/angular/angular.js:9777:9)
```

---

these are the bourbon items being returned in the browser console. all of them have the same bourbonId, starting with index 0.  Unique filter is returning 2 bourbon objects now, (the original and one of the duplicates?) instead of all of them... :

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object$$hashKey: "object:6"**v: 0avgRating: 4blog: "fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj"bourbonId: "54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c"comments: Array[0]distillery: "woodford"location: "kentucky"name: "woodford reserve"photo: "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg"__proto**: Object1: Object__v: 0avgRating: 4blog: "fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj"bourbonId: "54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c"comments: Array[0]distillery: "woodford"location: "kentucky"name: "woodford reserve"photo: "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg"**proto**: Object2: Object$$hashKey: "object:7"**v: 0avgRating: 0blog: "fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj"bourbonId: "54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c"comments: Array[0]length: 0__proto**: Array[0]distillery: "woodford"location: "kentucky"name: "woodford reserve"photo: "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg"**proto**: Object3: Object__v: 0avgRating: 0blog: "fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj"bourbonId: "54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c"comments: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]distillery: "woodford"location: "kentucky"name: "woodford reserve"photo: "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg"**proto**: Object4: Object__v: 0avgRating: 0blog: "fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj"bourbonId: "54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c"comments: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]distillery: "woodford"location: "kentucky"name: "woodford reserve"photo: "http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg"**proto**: Objectlength: 5__proto__: Array[0]

---

I think I've narrowed this to being an issue on the server side, within the controller / aggregate listed above. I need to find a way to replace the updated documents, instead of creating a new one each time the Bourbon.all is called / run on the client side / browser ... trying to tackle it now. Any tips, much appreciated.

Comment: add `ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons track by id` id would be your unique key of object.

Comment: thx. I was just looking into that: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

Comment: use `ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons track by bourbon.bourbonId'` should work

Comment: I'll try again, but that's what i'm doing to receive the error in the comment above.  it shows the first time, then on refresh / reload , it give a duplicate error.

Comment: try this last time `ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons track by $index'`

Comment: it's not returning an error, but the duplication still occurs. Starting to think this may be more on the server side.

Comment: looks like server is returning the duplicate data..could you check chrome developer tool network bar. does server is returning that or not?

Comment: does it server side issue?

Comment: looking under network to see if I can find it. Do you see anything on my server-side controller / aggregate that would cause the duplication?

Comment: this is all I see on the 'response headers' on the 'get' for the Bourbon.all function :  cache-control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 23 Jan 2015 21:34:52 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
vary:accept-encoding

Comment: you are looking at headers tab, try to look beside tab..`Preview` or `Response`

Comment: oh, right. this is what i'm getting in 'response' : {"bourbons":[{"name":"woodford reserve","location":"kentucky","distillery":"woodford","blog":"fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj","__v":0,"comments":[],"photo":"http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg","bourbonId":"54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c","avgRating":4},{"name":"woodford reserve","location":"kentucky","distillery":"woodford","blog":"fjkd;asdljfkld;ksdfj","__v":0,"comments":[],"photo":"http://aries-wineny.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/woodford-reserve.jpg","bourbonId":"54c2aa5556267e0000b5618c","avgRating":0},

Comment: That is what server side problem...you could try my solution..I've added the answer

Comment: thanks I'll try it out. Could be a good patch until I figure out what's up on the server side.

Comment: `findAndModify` instead of `find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be just a case of taking an example too literally. You're ending up with duplicated output on each request because that is how the store where the results are coming from is scoped.

So instead of this:

```
'use strict';

var Bourbon = require('../../../models/bourbon'),
    Comment = require('../../../models/comment'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    db = new DataStore(),          // <-- globally scoped in the module :(
    async = require('async');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Get Bourbons',
    notes: 'Get Bourbons',
    tags: ['bourbons'],
    handler: function(request, reply){

        async.series(
            [
                function(callback){
```

Rather do this:

```
'use strict';

var Bourbon = require('../../../models/bourbon'),
    Comment = require('../../../models/comment'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    async = require('async');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Get Bourbons',
    notes: 'Get Bourbons',
    tags: ['bourbons'],
    handler: function(request, reply){

        db = new DataStore();   // <--- Init store within request scope :)

        async.series(
            [
                function(callback){
```

Comment: not sure whether to laugh or cry..  Thx. the journey continues.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be issue from server side add track by $index will fix the issue.

`ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons track by $index`

But the thing is, it will show the duplicate records.

Better you use AngularUI [**angular.unique filter**](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)

First add the JS from link & then add 'ui.filters' module inside app dependancy.

`ng-repeat='bourbon in bourbons | unique:'bourbonId'`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: i've tried this, and I tried findAndModify.. neither working just yet. findAndModify is giving me a cannot find method findAndModify , but from what I understand from the documentation, that's supposed to be built into mongoose / mongodb..

Comment: this unique filter should have work anyhow..have you included the js https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js and relative module inside you app `'ui.filters'`

Comment: I used angular-ui-utils, which seems to include a unique filter. I'll try that one instead.

Comment: okay, I took out the $index, and the unique filter seems to be working... somewhat.. still allowing 1 duplicate..

Comment: each time I refresh, it adds a duplicate object, currenlty -- there are 4 duplicates. With the unique filter, the original shows, and 1 of the duplicates instead of all of the duplicates as it was before. When I restart the server, it erases the duplicates.. so I guess it's being put in browser storage...? not sure how this it working..

Comment: http://rachufour.org/alyce/2015/01/04/document-sub-arrays-stored-as-duplicate-values-of-the-first-entry-in-mongo/ some what related to your issue

Comment: unique filter working fine..might be the object whIch it is showing has different 'bourbonId'

Comment: I think there is some problem with db..you can mark my soltution..if it does helped you.